# Integrate linkedIn API in AngularJS project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, linkedin-api

I'm new to Angular and Javascript and i am trying to integrate the linkedIn API to sign up in my angularJS project, to autofill some forms, with the linkedIn data. I already tested it but everything in the same file(in the view) like this:

```
 <script type="in/login" data-onAuth="onLinkedInAuth">  </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

   function onLinkedInAuth() {
     IN.API
     .Raw('/people/~:(id,firstName,lastName,formatted-name,num-connections,location,positions:(id,title,summary,start-date,end-date,is-current,company:(id,name,type,size,industry,ticker)),summary,email-address,specialties)?format=json')
     .method('GET')
     .result(getResults)
     .error(onError)

   };

   function getResults(result) {
     console.log(result);
     document.getElementById('full_name').value = result.formattedName || '';
     document.getElementById('local').value = result.location.country.code || '';
     document.getElementById('summary').value = result.summary || '';
     document.getElementById('email_address').value = result.emailAddress || '';

   }

   function onError(error) {
     console.log(error)
   }
 </script>
```

but now i want to do all this, but using services and controllers something like:

Press LinkedIn Button -> controller -> Service -> linkeInAPI -> service -> controller -> view(fill forms with data, to multiple views in this case).

I already created a linkedInService.js, linkedInController.js.

the problem is that i dont really know how to do this, because i'm new to all this. If someone could help me out that would be great.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Usually an angularjs project contains various files that have various purposes.

This is a possible project structure of an angularjs project (taken from [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure) site) please not that this structure is not perfect and there are even better ways to structure your angularjs code (the example in [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure) article explanis this really well) but this is a simple structure that you could start off

```
app/
----- controllers/ --> controllers "glue" together html files with code logic
---------- mainController.js
---------- otherController.js
----- directives/
---------- mainDirective.js
---------- otherDirective.js
----- services/ --> services are reusable functions that you define that can get reused in controllers
---------- userService.js 
---------- itemService.js
----- js/
---------- bootstrap.js
---------- jquery.js
----- app.js
views/
----- mainView.html
----- otherView.html
----- index.html
```

so one possible starting point would be to add all the linkedin related code into a LinkedinService and then to call this LinkedinService from within your controllers:

```
  .service('LinkedinService', function ($http){

        this.loginWithLinkedin = function (){

         return IN.API
               .Raw('/people/~:(id,firstName,lastName,formatted-name,num-connections,location,positions:(id,title,summary,start-date,end-date,is-current,company:(id,name,type,size,industry,ticker)),summary,email-address,specialties)?format=json').method('GET')
        };
```

and then call in one of your controllers:

```
LinkedinService.loginWithLinkedin().then(function (data) {
    console.log('linkedin login data:', data);

   })
```

I also see that you are changing the dom with `document.getElementById('email_address').value =` 
This should be avoided in angularjs because it supposed to be done with [scopes](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_scopes.asp)